# php adding up checkboxes

Tags: php, forms

I have a list of check boxs that are displaying right and retunring the values of all that are checked. I use that in one part of my code but would also like to get the number or boxes check. The checkboxes are like so:

```
<div id="ironSet">
                                Include in Set
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="3" />
    <span class="smallfont">3</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="4" />
    <span class="smallfont">4</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="5" />
    <span class="smallfont">5</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="6" />
    <span class="smallfont">6</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="7" />
    <span class="smallfont">7</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="8" />
    <span class="smallfont">8</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="9" />
    <span class="smallfont">9</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="PW" />
    <span class="smallfont">PW</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="TW" />
    <span class="smallfont">TW</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="iron[]" value="SW" />
     <span class="smallfont">SW</span>
</div>
```

I echo these values in a php review form like so

```
$iron = join(", ", $_REQUEST["iron"]);

echo (!empty($_REQUEST['iron'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>In Set:</span>{$iron}</div>" : "";
```

This would return the values, if any, for all that are checked. Is there a way I can get the number of `"iron[]"` boxes check as will and store it in another variable? I am trying to multiply the number of boxes checked by a price variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As checkboxes are returned as an array, you should be able to simply do a count on them as far as I recall. This is because only boxes that are checked are sent though in the request.

```
$boxesChecked=count($_REQUEST["iron"]);
echo $boxesChecked;
```

from there, you can simply apply your logic as needed:

```
if($boxesChecked>5) // apply 20% discount
{
    $dollarValue*=0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][0]; // 3
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][1]; // 4
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][2]; // 5
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][3]; // 6
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][4]; // 7
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][5]; // 8
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][6]; // 9
echo $_REQUEST['iron'][7]; // pw
```

and apply your conditions on these.. u can use loop to determine weather it checked or not

```
foreach( $_REQUEST['iron'] as $val)
{
  if(!empty($val))
 {
 echo $val;
 }
}
```